# Cannot find an overload with ForEach loop

Tags: .net, powershell, foreach

this is my powershell code :

```
$SourceZipFolder = "C:\temp\TEST\tempzip"

New-Item -type directory -path $SourceZipFolder

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" ) | Out-Null

$CompressionLevel= [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal

$FileSource = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\TEST" | Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-2)


Move-Item $FileSource.FullName -Destination $SourceZipFolder

Foreach ($Fichiers in $FileSource) {
$ZipDestination ="C:\temp\TEST\archive\$($Fichiers.Name).zip"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($SourceZipFolder, $ZipDestination, $CompressionLevel)
}

Remove-Item -Path $SourceZipFolder -Recurse
```

I got this error while executing it :

```
Cannot find an overload for "CreateFromDirectory" and the argument count: "3".
At C:\Users\test\Desktop\temp.ps1:17 char:1
+ [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($SourceZipFolder, $ZipDestination, ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

My `ForEach` loop doesn't accept `$CompressionLevel` parameter in `[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory` and I don't understand why... because when I use `For` loop instead of `ForEach` It works...

Thansk for your help

I use Powershell V4.

Comment: A does not see any overload of [`CreateFromDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory.aspx) with three arguments.

Comment: There is an overload for `CreateFromDirectory` with three arguments but the method signature is CreateFromDirectory(String, String, Encoding). However, you are trying to pass it a CompressionLevel as the Encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set a compression level and don't care about the encoding type then you need to use the following method signature:

```
CreateFromDirectory(String, String, CompressionLevel, Boolean)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For the relevant section of your code:

```
Foreach ($Fichiers in $FileSource) {
    $ZipDestination ="C:\temp\TEST\archive\$($Fichiers.Name).zip"
    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($SourceZipFolder, $ZipDestination, $CompressionLevel, $false)
}
```

Note the additional parameter at the end. You will want to use $true if you want the base source directory to be included in the zip file and $false if you just want the contents of the source directory to be in the zip file.